# How to Save Relational Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4.1

I have a string list which I need to save to a relational entity.

```
Dim ts = (From t In _repository.GetSettings _
               Where t.TrustSettingId = Setting.SettingId).First()

For i As Integer = 0 To emailAddressList.Count()
        If(Not emailAddressList(i) = ts.SettingEmailAddresses(i).EmailAddress)
            ts.SettingEmailAddresses.Add(New SettingHREmailAddress() With {.EmailAddress = emailAddressList(i)})
        End If
    Next
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'TrustSettingEmailAddress' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you that it cannot save data to `TrustSettingEmailAddress` because it most probably doesn't have primary key defined in your model. `DefiningQuery` is automatically used if you try to add database view or table without primary key to EDMX. This also happens for junction tables in many-to-many relation.